# How to use a colormap in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to read a custom image and apply a colormap like in the example from matlab. How can I do that? I see the example `imageext` uses custom images and applies colormaps and I'd like to do the same with my images. How can it be done? I want just to use my own picture for an example like `imageext` in matlab.

This does not work:

`I = im2double(imread('niklas3.png')); figure(1); imshow(I,[]); daspect([1 1 1]); axis off; colormap gray;`

niklas3.png:

[image]

But this code works:

`I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')); figure(1); imshow(I,[]); daspect([1 1 1]); axis off; colormap summer;`

Comment: Not clear, do you expect to put in an array with an single channel image and get out 3 color channels or do you just want to visualize it with a colormap?

Comment: Can you please include the example you're referring to? Either by adding a link or better by including the image directly.

Comment: I want a colormap effect with my photo similar to what happens with `I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')); figure(1); imshow(I,[]); daspect([1 1 1]); axis off; colormap summer;`. But colormap never works with my images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a colormap in any image you want if it was previously displayed into a figure.

I recommend you to use *imagesc* or *imshow* to display images. In order to do that, you need to load the image with *imread*. A good practice is to convert your image data to double precision.

```
I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
```

As you can see, *im2double* converts image data to double precision ranging from 0 values to 1 values. If you do not want this, you can use the *double* function, ranging from 0 values to 255 value.

Later, you need to display the image into a figure. I strongly recommend to use *imagesc* instead of *imshow*, because *imagesc* allows you to customize your data and your display (for example, adding a different colormap).

```
figure(1); imagesc(I); daspect([1 1 1]); axis off;
```

Now, you can use the colormap you want. Type *help colormap* for more information, but you can use a *jet* colormap (default), *gray*, *hot*, *bones*, or whatever you want, just typing:

```
colormap gray;
```

If you plotted several images, you need to indicate the aimed image with:

```
figure(1); colormap gray;
```

If you want to use *imshow*, just type:

```
figure(1); imshow(I,[]); daspect([1 1 1]); axis off; colormap gray;
```

**Edited:** Once I saw your image, I knew your problem is that you are trying to apply a colormap into a RGB image. That is, you are trying to apply it into a 3D matrix, where rows and columns identify the pixel value and the third dimension identifies the RGB components.

So, you need to convert your RGB image into a 2D matrix (a black and white one). You can do it by performing the mean along the third dimension.

```
I = nanmean(I,3);
```

Finally, you should apply the colormap as I said it before. The final code would be:

```
I = im2double(imread('niklas3.jpg'));
I = nanmean(I,3);
figure(1); imshow(I,[]); daspect([1 1 1 ]); axis off;
colormap jet;
```

This is the result using a *jet* colormap:

[image: Jet colormap applied to the RGB image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it is not working for me. The colormap does not apply to the image that is in my figure. Everything works except the colormap and I don't get an error message.

Comment: Copy and paste your code. Maybe I can help you if you do that.

Comment: I tried with this code ` I = im2double(imread('niklas2.jpg')); figure(1); imread(I,[]); daspect([1 1 1]); axis off; colormap gray;` which loaded the image onto a figure but it didn't apply the colormap.

Comment: Sorry, I write *imread* instead of *imshow*. But you should get an error:

I = im2double(imread('niklas2.jpg')); figure(1); imshow(I,[]); daspect([1 1 1]); axis off; colormap gray;

Maybe is the jpg. Can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: This doesn't work and I don't get an error message: `I = im2double(imread('niklas3.png')); figure(1); imshow(I,[]); daspect([1 1 1]); axis off; colormap gray;`. I tried with many different images and it never works.

Comment: It seems weird to me. Obviously, if your image is in black & white, the code is already working because *colormap gray* uses a black & white colormap. In that case, you could see the differences using *colormap jet* or something similar. 

I can't help you without more information. Try to load a pre-defined image like 'cameraman.tif' and write that line again. I usually work with images in matlab and this code **always** works.

Comment: Yes it's weird. The code with cameraman.tif works but not with my pictures. I've uploaded one of my pics to the question. Maybe there is something wrong with my images but what could that be?

Comment: Probably your problem is that you are loading a RGB image, so you are trying to plot a 3D matrix, with pixels information in rows and cols, and RGB components in the third dimension. That could be the reason, because you cannot apply a colormap to 3 dimensions at the same time. I recommend you to calculate the RGB mean in order to get a b&w image: *I=nanmean(I,3);*. Next, display the result and apply the colormap. I do not have MatLab here, but I will try it later.